# Finding index position of a character in a string and use it in substring functions in dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

data frame :

[image]

I need to truncate the String column value based on the # position. The result should be :

[image]

I am trying this code but it is throwing a TypeError :

[image]

Though I can achieve the desired result using SparkSql or by creating a function in Python, is there any way that it can be done in pyspark itself?

Comment: Post your code as text, not as pictures. It will be way easier to help

Comment: The error occurs because `substr()` takes two Integer type values as arguments, whereas the code indicates one is `Integer` type value and the other is a `class 'pyspark.sql.column.Column'` type value

Comment: okay, this make sense now. So IndexPosition column that I am creating is of Column class though the data type of column is integer, right?

Comment: Yes, The column might be `IntegerType` but not an integer object (substr expects 2 integer objects as arguments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is to use `locate` within the `substr` function, but this can only be used with `expr`.

```py
spark.sparkContext.parallelize([('WALGREENS #6411',), ('CVS/PHARMACY #08864',), ('CVS',)]).toDF(['acct']). \
    withColumn('acct_name', 
               func.when(func.col('acct').like('%#%') == False, func.col('acct')).
               otherwise(func.expr('substr(acct, 1, locate("#", acct)-2)'))
               ). \
    show()

# +-------------------+------------+
# |               acct|   acct_name|
# +-------------------+------------+
# |    WALGREENS #6411|   WALGREENS|
# |CVS/PHARMACY #08864|CVS/PHARMACY|
# |                CVS|         CVS|
# +-------------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split()` function to achieve this. I used split function with delimiter as `#` to get the required value and removed leading spaces with `rtrim()`.

- My input:

```
+---+-------------------+
| id|             string|
+---+-------------------+
|  1|    WALGREENS #6411|
|  2|CVS/PHARMACY #08864|
|  3|                CVS|
|  4|          WALGREENS|
|  5|         Test #1234|
+---+-------------------+
```

- Try using the following code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split,col,rtrim

df = df.withColumn("New_string", split(col("string"), "#").getItem(0))
#you can also use substring_index() 
#df.withColumn("result", substring_index(df['string'], '#',1))

df = df.withColumn('New_string', rtrim(df['New_string']))

df.show()
```

- Output:
  [image]